# Understanding “haven’t got very far” in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, perfect-constructions

When I saw this sentence, there seems to be something  weird to me. I got this sentence from [Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries,](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get) entry number 11.

> I haven't got very far with the book I'm reading.

'Got' means 'to arrive', by the way

Firstly, why does this clause use forming of present perfect?

Second, Does this sentence need the expression of 'very far'?

I don't know exact meaning of it.

Comment: Note that for AmE we use "gotten"

Answer (score 1):

To 'get far' or 'get very far' means to make progress.

> **Far**
>
> **3 used for saying or asking how much progress someone or something
>   makes**
>
> How far have you got with the planning?
>
> We want to stress just how far the committee has progressed.
>
> We’re not going to get very far if we don’t trust each other.

[Far (adjective) (MacMillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/far)